# How to detect Links with out anchor element in a plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If user enters his text in the text box and saves it and again what's to add some more text he can edit that text and save it if required.

Firstly if user enters that text with some links I, detected them and converted any hyperlinks to linkify in new tab. Secondly if user wants to add some more text and links he clicks on edit and add them and save it at this time I must ignore the links that already hyperlinked with anchor button

Please help and advice

For example:

```
what = "<span>In the task system, is there a way to automatically have any site / page URL or image URL be hyperlinked in a new window?</span><br><br><span>So If I type or copy http://www.stackoverflow.com/&nbsp; for example anywhere in the description, in any of the internal messages or messages to clients, it automatically is a hyperlink in a new window.</span><br><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">http://www.stackoverflow.com/</a><br>    <br><span>Or if I input an image URL anywhere in support description, internal messages or messages to cleints, it automatically is a hyperlink in a new window:</span><br> <span>https://static.doubleclick.net/viewad/4327673/1-728x90.jpg</span><br><br><a href="https://static.doubleclick.net/viewad/4327673/1-728x90.jpg">https://static.doubleclick.net/viewad/4327673/1-728x90.jpg</a><br><br><br><span>This would save us a lot time in task building, reviewing and creating messages.</span>



Test URL's
        http://www.stackoverflow.com/
        http://stackoverflow.com/
        https://stackoverflow.com/
        www.stackoverflow.com
        //stackoverflow.com/
        <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>http://stackoverflow.com/</a>";
```

I've tried this code

```
function Linkify(what) {
    str = what; out = ""; url = ""; i = 0;
    do {
        url = str.match(/((https?:\/\/)?([a-z\-]+\.)*[\-\w]+(\.[a-z]{2,4})+(\/[\w\_\-\?\=\&\.]*)*(?![a-z]))/i);
        if(url!=null) {
            // get href value
            href = url[0];
            if(href.substr(0,7)!="http://") href = "http://"+href;

            // where the match occured
            where = str.indexOf(url[0]);

            // add it to the output
            out += str.substr(0,where);

            // link it
            out += '<a href="'+href+'" target="_blank">'+url[0]+'</a>';

            // prepare str for next round
            str = str.substr((where+url[0].length));
        } else {
            out += str;
            str = "";
        }
    } while(str.length>0);
    return out;
}
```

Please help
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle?

Comment: why don't you just use `str.replace(/yourRegExp/, '')` ?

Comment: @Dwza replace / match doesn't matter how can i ignore the links that already hyperlinked with anchor button

Comment: Here is my another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301080/autolink-url-in-contenteditable-iframe) and got answer

Answer (score 3):

here is a regex where you select all the links without having anchors

```
(?:(?:http(?:s)?(?:\:\/\/))?(?:www\.)?(?:\w)*(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\/?))(?!([\/a-z<\/a>])|(\'|\"))
```

Here is a **[RegExFiddle](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KEYGHGP6I3ArLpgm)** *(updated 14:41)*

quit a lil difficult task because in javascript you don't have a `preceded by` statement. :)

**EDIT1:** Now it detects...

```
http://www.abc.xy
http://abc.xy
https://www.abc.xy
https://abc.xy
www.abc.xy
abc.xy
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is it a little shorted and the usage fiddle

Regex

```
/((http(s)?(\:\/\/))?(www\.)?(\w)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\/?))(?!([\/a-z<\/a>])|(\'|\"))/g
```

function

```
function Linkify(str) {
    var newStr =  str.replace(/((http(s)?(\:\/\/))?(www\.)?(\w)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\/?))(?!([\/a-z<\/a>])|(\'|\"))/g,'<a href="$1">$1</a>');
    return newStr;
}

var newData = Linkify(data);
```

**[WORKING JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/ce5N9/)**

**EDIT 1.000.000 :D**

```
/((http(s)?(\:\/\/))?(www\.)?([\w\-\.\/])*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\/?))(?!(.*a>)|(\'|\"))/g
```

this solves your problem now.

the only problem you will run in here is, 4 letters after a dot is not selected. e.g `.info` if you want them selected than change `{2,3}` to `{2,4}` BUT be carefully... if someone adds a text like `my name is.john` than `is.john` will be translated to a link.

**EDIT 2.0**

If you have a really complex URL like the following

```
((http(s)?(\:\/\/))?(www\.)?([\a-zA-Z0-9-_\.\/])*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\/?))([\a-zA-Z0-9-_\/?=&#])*(?!(.*a>)|(\'|\"))
```

Matches

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170950/summernote-inserthtml?firstname=channaveer&lastname=hakari#fsdfsdf
```

Comment: did you test the given regx ?

Comment: @dhee sorry, im at work :) updated the regex, now it also detects www.

Comment: @dhee would be nice if you accept the answere if this solved your problem :)

Comment: i'm still facing some issues with this regx :(

Comment: Dwza test with this url it fails :( https://static.doubleclick.net/viewad/4327673/1-728x90.jpg im poor in regx formation or creation can you please help

Comment: @dhee done :D if you want some more changes, you have to invite me at least for a coke ;D

Comment: @dhee i already did. dont you saw my changes ? see my edit 1.000.000 :D

Comment: Waw this works fine in [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) if this works in my site i'll accept the answere and thank you so much

Comment: Ur EDIT 1.000.000 expression ignoring the urls in any html tags. like span. How can u ignore only urls in <a></a>.

Comment: @mmssaann first it doesn't ignores all html tags, its just lil buggy on other tags selecting the `.com` or `.de` or what ever... i fixed it by replacing `[\/a-z<\/a>]` with `.*a>`, post updated. `<span href='www.abc.xy'>www.abc.xy</span>` would make no sense anyway... or what is your tag you using ? `<span>www.abc.xy</span>`is no problem.

Comment: @Dwza i realized that i can't solve my problem using regex :( i'm getting new bugs while trying in this method. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

A more simple solution is probably to strip the links which you created (so the user gets exactly what they typed when they click "Edit" again).

Another idea is to split the string at `</a>`. That gives you a list of strings which all end with an anchor element (except the last one). Iterate over this list, cut away the part after the last `<a`, linkify.