# Javascript InnerHTML not working on a DIV within a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have integrated summernote6  text editor into my website , i have a button that when pressed should change the default text content inside of the summernote6 text editor.

I am using javascript for the function which uses innerhtml to modify the below HTML to change the heading , However when i press the button nothing happens , but if i move the id "headingram" to the DIV one level above it changes the entire thing , however changing this DIV gets rid of the whole text box which is not what i want.

```
<div class="panel-body no-padding">
<div class="summernote6" id="headingram">
    <h5>Hello Jonathan!</h5>

</div>
```

```
function HeadingChanger(){
let HeadingTitle = document.getElementById('headingram').innerHTML ="<H1>HELLO</H1>";
console.log(HeadingTitle);}
```

i have a seperate button that calls the headinchanger() function , i know this works because when i move the id to the DIV above it changes

Comment: your question was edited to "fix" it, but I rolled it back because **you** should provide exactly the markup and code you have; the fixer has to guess — if "the closing div did not come through when [you] pasted the code" you should fix it.

Comment: Take your time and read the summernote docs. See post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34171433/8043806

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue stems from not having a closing div tag for the outer div:

```js
function HeadingChanger() {
  let HeadingTitle = document.getElementById('headingram').innerHTML = "<H1>HELLO</H1>";
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body no-padding">
  <div class="summernote6" id="headingram">
    <h5>Hello Jonathan!</h5>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="HeadingChanger();">Click</button>
```

Comment: sorry the closing div did not come through when i pasted the code but it is present and even with it , it does not work

Comment: I thought it might only be a copying mistake. But that meant that the code you provided works, right? What is the result you are looking for?

Comment: no it doesn't work , the text on the screen does not change.

Comment: Your code works in the snippet though. So if it still doesn't work for you, there must be something else in your environment that is interfering somehow. Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @TinasheShoko I tried the code on the question as it stands at the moment of writing. It works for me. Are you sure you have the JavaScript function running on click?